# Trying to execute a function in a row of the ListView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a LisView in my component as follow:

```
class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.dataSource),
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.dataSource !== nextProps.dataSource) {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.dataSource),
      });
    }
  }

  onPressRow(key) {
    console.log(key);
  }

  getListView() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      return (
        <ActivityIndicator
          animating
          size={'small'}
          style={styles.spinner}
          color={this.props.activityIndicatorColor}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <ListView
        style={styles.listView}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps
        keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      />
    );
  }

  renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.listButton}
      >
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.onPressRow(rowData)}
        >
          <Text>
            {rowData.description}
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          // TEXTINPUT
        </View>
        {this.getListView()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

When i click on a row i want execute a function but i have this error:

> _this2.onPressRow is not a function

Why i can't to read the function? i must pass it as a props?

Comment: Bind your `renderRow` also, like `renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}`

Comment: Thank you @Cherniv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `React.createClass`, all calls are automatically binded, but when using the ES6 approach of `extends React.Component` you have to bind all your functions.

You can do it either inline using

```
renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
```

Alternatively, you can add to your constructor, after `super()`:

```
this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
```

Personally I like this approach as I find this code a bit easier to read.

For more information about the ES6 way, check [this link](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/).